# Everything an Object in python but why not keywords as Objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python programming, beauty of python is Everything an Object but why not keywords as Objects?

```
>>> type(for)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    type(for)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: "Everything is an object" is neither beautiful, nor true in Python.

Comment: At risk of being Captain Obvious... But maybe because they are keywords and operators and not objects? :) Why would you want them to be objects?

Comment: There's an exception to *nearly* everything.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, operators are objects; Have a look at the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module. You cannot get the operator objects with their usual name (since that would significantly complicate Python's grammar, and be confusing), but this works:

```
>>> import operator
>>> type(operator.add)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Flow control keywords such as `if` and `for` are not objects because there is no semantic - what would you do with a hypothetical `for` object? Note that there *are* functions that can replace a for loop, namely [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter), [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce), and a variety of functions in [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

Comment: I suppose `for` and `if` could have been made to be functions, but that would probably require some semantic gymnastics that nobody actually wants.

Comment: @kojiro There are functions for common cases, and you can easily make your own, but the result won't be as easy to understand (lots of anonymous functions), and therefore not pythonic.

Comment: The `operator` module appears to be convenience functions wrapping the built-in operators, not the operators themselves. Not sure that counts.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, the functions look like an operator, work like a operator, and quack like an operator ... and Python uses duck typing.

Comment: Mark is right: Operators are not objects. The operator module contains functions that wrap the operators. That doesn't count as the operators being objects themselves. These functions are for example not called when you use the operators.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that operators and keywords are not objects is that they are really just part of the syntax of the language, rather than elements on which you can operate. As phihag said, what would you do with a hypothetical 'for' object?

Operators, however, are objects - but you have to remember that the '+' operator is essentially just syntactic sugar for the **add** function. When you write

```
a + b * c
```

what Python sees (ignoring optimizations) is more like

```
a.__add__(b.__mul__(c))
```

In fact, we can try this with numbers:

```
>>> (5).__mul__((3).__add__(10))
65
```

Thus, the operator '+' is represented by the (5).__ add__ function, which is an object. (We have to use parentheses because numeric literals are a special syntactic case.)

Comment: It's a little bit more than syntactic sugar; observe `(2).__add__('')`.

Answer (score 1):

There is some mixed messaging going on. Mark Pilgrim says [Everything is an Object](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html), but even in languages where everything is an object, not *everything* is an object. ;)

Python lets you do operator overloading via specially named methods for a class. It also has an `operator` module. Ultimately, though, both members of the `operator` module and special operator class methods are *functions* and therefore objects, but the *bare word* (such as `+`) that Python uses to provide readability and semantics is simply not always parseable as an object.

This is a little less true for keywords. Some keywords, such as `if`, don't boil down to an object at all. It's probably best to ignore the word *everything* in Dive Into Python and just remember this quote:

> Strings are objects. Lists are objects. Functions are objects. Even
>   modules are objects.

Answer (score 0):

Keywords do not exist as something within Python. You get a syntax error, but if you didn't, you still can't do type(keyword) because the keyword doesn't exist.

Take the following code as an example:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlparse as foo
```

Here we see the word "as" as a part of the syntax. It's a keyword.

```
>>> type(as)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    as
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But trying to use it as an object results in a syntax error.

But in 2.4 `as` is not a reserved word. So there things are different:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlparse as foo
```

So far so good.

```
>>> type(as)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
NameError: name 'as' is not defined
```

There we see that `as` simply doesn't exist. It's not an object, because it isn't anything. The language is not aware of it's existence. This is because the language can not be aware of something before it's executed. And the parsing is done before execution. Hence, the parsing of the syntax and the keyword is done before "everything" exists. Therefore keywords are not a part of "everything" and therefore they are not objects.

The syntax errors you get are to prevent you from making mistakes by using keywords as variable names. In this case though, this error means it's not immediately obvious why keywords aren't objects: Because they aren't anything.